# How to concatenate 2 cells at the top of a filtered list? (EXCEL macros)

Tags: excel, vba

So i've searched for hours now, and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.
I have a list of 13000+ rows, but I have auto filtered it down to about 200, now what I want is that, lets assume, the top of the list now shows as A1 then straight to A28 because of the filter.
I want the text in cell A28 and B28 to be concatenated and put in cell J28.
I am able to do this manually easily, but when I record the actions for a macro this code comes up

```
    Sub concat()
'
' concat Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]&RC[-8]"
    Range("J28").Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Now I'm not sure what

```
"=RC[-9]&RC[-8]"
```

means but when I run the macro it does not result in what I want.

If I am unclear on this problem, I apologize in advance but I really do need help.

Thanks!

Varun

Comment: Can you just concatenate it for the entire column? Is there a reason that J can't equal A & B all the time?

Comment: I need it to be concatenated after the filtering as well. So I guess that could work, the formula created by the recording macro is what is buggy for me I believe

Comment: That formula will result in `=A28+B28` in J28. (It means the cell 9 columns to the left, plus the cell 8 columns to the left.) It sounds like that's what you want. Can you clarify what's wrong with that?

Comment: How can I make that reference from a28+b28 to a2+b2 then fill down to used range :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but you have to turn off the filter first:

```
Sub FillDown()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("J2:J" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]&RC[-8]"
End With
End Sub
```

I'm not clear why you don't just turn off the filter and manually copy down the formula as far as necessary.

Comment: Perfect except I changed the + to an &
Thanks!

Comment: Woops, I'll edit that, forgot the original question :). I'm glad it works.